How to prove a formula on sum of products of alternating sign Vandermonde convolution?
The alternating sign Vandermonde convolution refers to the following sum
\begin{align}
V(r,s,N) = \sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^k \tbinom{r}{k}\tbinom{s}{N-k}.
\end{align}
Let $\Delta^{\pm} (m_0,m_1) := |m_0\pm m_1|$, how can I prove that
\begin{align}
\sum_{q=0}^n V(m_0,n-m_0,q) V(m_1,n-m_1,q) = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{\frac{\Delta^-}{2}}\frac{\Delta^+!(2n-\Delta^+)!}{\frac{\Delta^+}{2}!(n-\frac{\Delta^+}{2})!n!}, & \Delta^-\text{ is even},\\
0, & \Delta^-\text{ is odd},
\end{cases}
\end{align}
for $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0},\, m_{0,1}\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0},\, m_{0,1}\le n$?
Background: I read this from Eq. (C5) in a research paper, where it is used without explanation.
My attempts:
I did numerical check on this formula, then searched relevant questions on MSE.
Thanks to alternating sign Vandermonde convolution, I learned that
\begin{align}
V(r,s,q) = \tbinom{s}{q} {}_2F_1(-r,-q;s-q+1;-1)
\end{align}
for $s\ge q$, but there are no hypergeometric closed formulas for the general case. Also I learned that
\begin{align}
V(r,s,q) = [x^q](1-x)^r(1+x)^s\,,
\end{align}
but for now I couldn't proceed further.
Update (refined statement):
From MSE 4131219, 4320991 and 4731417, V(m,n-m,q) is the Kravchuk polynomial
\begin{align}
\mathcal{K}_q(m;n,2) = \sum_{k=0}^q (-1)^k {m \choose k}{n-m \choose q-k}\,.
\end{align}
We are interested in
\begin{align}
 S(n,m_0,m_1) = \sum_{q=0}^{n}\mathcal{K}_q(m_0;n,2)\mathcal{K}_q(m_1;n,2)\,.
\end{align}
Using the symmetry relations,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{K}_q(m;n,2) = \frac{n \choose q}{n \choose m}\mathcal{K}_m(q;n,2)\,,
\end{align}
the sum translates into
\begin{align}
 S(n,m_0,m_1) = \tbinom{n}{m_0}^{-1}\tbinom{n}{m_1}^{-1}\sum_{q=0}^{n}  \tbinom{n}{q}^2 \mathcal{K}_{m_0}(q;n,2)\mathcal{K}_{m_1}(q;n,2)\,.
\end{align}

Introducing
$$V(r,s,N) = \sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^k {r\choose k} {s\choose N-k}
= [z^N] (1+z)^s \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k {r\choose k} z^k
\\ = [z^N] (1+z)^s (1-z)^r$$
we seek a closed form of
$$S(n,m_0,m_1) = \sum_{q=0}^n V(m_0,n-m_0,q) V(m_1,n-m_1,q)$$
where $n\ge 1$ and $0\le m_{0,1}\le n.$ We obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^n V(m_0,n-m_0,n-q) V(m_1,n-m_1,n-q)
\\ = [w^n] (1+w)^{n-m_0} (1-w)^{m_0}
[z^n] (1+z)^{n-m_1} (1-z)^{m_1}
\sum_{q=0}^n w^q z^q.$$
Here we may extend the sum to infinity due to the coefficient
extractors:
$$[w^n] (1+w)^{n-m_0} (1-w)^{m_0}
[z^n] (1+z)^{n-m_1} (1-z)^{m_1} \frac{1}{1-wz}.$$
The contribution from $z$ is
$$-\frac{1}{w} \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{n-m_1} (1-z)^{m_1} \frac{1}{z-1/w}.$$
Here the residue at infinity  is zero (just barely) and
residues sum to zero so we may evaluate using minus the
residue at $z=1/w$, getting
$$[w^{n+1}] (1+w)^{n-m_0} (1-w)^{m_0}
w^{n+1} \frac{(1+w)^{n-m_1}}{w^{n-m_1}}
\frac{(w-1)^{m_1}}{w^{m_1}}
\\ = (-1)^{m_1} [w^n] (1+w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (1-w)^{m_0+m_1}.$$
This is
$$(-1)^{m_1} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (1-w)^{m_0+m_1}.$$
Note there  are no poles at  $\pm 1$ due to  the stated
boundary  conditions.  We   evaluate  using  minus  the
residue at infinity (residues again sum to zero):
$$(-1)^{m_1} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{w^{n+1}}{w^2} (1+1/w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (1-1/w)^{m_0+m_1}
\\ = (-1)^{m_1} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (w-1)^{m_0+m_1}
\\ = (-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (1-w)^{m_0+m_1}.$$
We thus have
$$S(n,m_0,m_1) = \frac{1}{2}
((-1)^{m_0}+(-1)^{m_1})
[w^n] (1+w)^{2n-m_0-m_1} (1-w)^{m_0+m_1}.$$
Here we clearly obtain a  zero value when $\Delta^-$ is
odd which is half the claim. Otherwise we have in terms
of $\Delta^+$
$$(-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{2n-\Delta^+} (1-w)^{\Delta^+}.$$
Now put $w/(1+w)=v$ so that $w=v/(1-v)$ and $dw = 1/(1-v)^2 \; dv$ to
get
$$(-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{n-1-\Delta^+}} 
\frac{(1-2v)^{\Delta^+}}{(1-v)^{\Delta+}}
\frac{1}{(1-v)^2}
\\ = (-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{n+1}} 
(1-2v)^{\Delta^+}.$$
Next put  $v=(1-\sqrt{1-4u})/2$ so that  $v(1-v)=u$ and
$dv = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4u}}\; du$ to get
$$(-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{n+1}} \sqrt{1-4u}^{\Delta^+}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4u}}
\\ = (-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{n+1}} \sqrt{1-4u}^{\Delta^+ -1}
= (-1)^{m_0} \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{n+1}} (1-4u)^{\Delta^+/2 -1/2}
\\ = (-1)^{m_0} {\Delta^+/2 -1/2\choose n} (-1)^n 4^n.$$
This is an acceptable closed form but apparently OP ask
for additional manipulation,  which is (use $\Delta^+/2
\le n$ as well as the fact that now $\Delta^+$ is even)
$$(-1)^{m_0} {\Delta^+/2 -1/2\choose \Delta^+/2}
(\Delta^+/2)! {-1/2\choose n-\Delta^+/2} (n-\Delta^+/2)!
\frac{1}{n!} (-1)^n 4^n
\\ = (-1)^{m_0+\Delta^+/2} {-1/2\choose \Delta^+/2}
(\Delta^+/2)! \frac{(-1)^{n-\Delta^+/2}}{4^{n-\Delta^+/2}} 
{2n-\Delta^+\choose n-\Delta^+/2}
(n-\Delta^+/2)! \frac{1}{n!} (-1)^n 4^n
\\ = (-1)^{m_0} \frac{(-1)^{\Delta^+/2}}{4^{\Delta^+/2}}
{\Delta^+\choose \Delta^+/2}
(\Delta^+/2)! \frac{1}{4^{n-\Delta^+/2}} 
\frac{(2n-\Delta^+)!}{(n-\Delta^+/2)!}
\frac{1}{n!} 4^n
\\ = (-1)^{m_0+\Delta^+/2}
\frac{\Delta^+!}{(\Delta^+/2)!}
\frac{(2n-\Delta^+)!}{(n-\Delta^+/2)!}
\frac{1}{n!}.$$
To  conclude  observe   that  $(-1)^{m_0+\Delta^+/2}  =
(-1)^{3m_0/2+m_1/2} = (-1)^{-m_0/2+m_1/2}$ to get
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^{\Delta^-/2}
\frac{\Delta^+!}{(\Delta^+/2)!}
\frac{(2n-\Delta^+)!}{(n-\Delta^+/2)!}
\frac{1}{n!}.}$$

Many thanks for this very nice answer! This clears everything up for me, and the substitution with v and u is clean and beautiful.
